# Convert overflow to negative

Tags: c, overflow

Is there an easy way to replace an overflow at counting down with a negative value?

For example a 32 bit variable. Possible values are 0x00000000 - 0xFFFFFFFF. When I subtract 1 from the lowest possible value (0x00000000 - 1), the result is 0xFFFFFFFF. How can the operation be changed to give a result of -1?

Comment: By making it `signed` type instead of `unsigned`. You cannot store the values `0x00000000` - `0xFFFFFFFF` *and* `-1` without going to 64-bit.

Comment: ...but beware, an overflow on `signed` is invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: Use `long long result = var_uint32_bit - 1LL;`

Comment: @chux-- would it be better to use `int64_t result`?

Comment: @DavidBowling True, either `long long` or `int64_t` would work when `int64_t` exists.  6.0001 vs 1/2 dozen of the other. I found it is less complicated to use `long long` throughout, else the `1LL` should be amended too.

Comment: @chux-- I did not realize that `long long` was guaranteed to be at least 64 bits wide; but I just checked the Standard, and there it is! So, at least 6.0001 vs 1/2 dozen....

Comment: Maybe it should be `int_least64_t` or `int_fast64_t`?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an easy way to replace an overflow at counting down with a negative value?

Use wider math is a direct approach.

"example a 32 bit variable. Possible values are 0x00000000 - 0xFFFFFFFF" implies that the variable is some *unsigned type* like `uint32_t`.

---

Subtracting 1 from `(uint32_t)0` is `(uint32_t)0xFFFFFFFF` as OP reported.  So instead use a wider *signed* math like `long long` (which is at least 64-bit) or `int64_t`

```
// Insure subtraction is done using `long long` math with 1LL
long long result = var_uint32_bit - 1LL;
```

---

Alternatively code could stick with a corresponding same width *signed* type.

```
// Only non-implementation defined for values 0...0x7FFFFFFF
int32_t result = (int32_t)var_uint32_bit - 1;
```

The `(int32_t)var_uint32_bit` has a limitation concerning conversion of an *unsigned* type to a *signed* integer type.

> Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised. C11dr §6.3.1.3 3